# How to select an item inside a dropdown list using the contents of a variable not an ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list that contains the following items:

Eastern Cape, ID = 1
Gauteng, ID = 2
KwaZulu Natal, ID 3
Mpumalanga, ID 4

I also have a variable named provinces. If I put, for example, Eastern Cape inside the variable and use the following code to select Eastern Cape, it does not get selected.

```
var provinces = "Eastern Cape";
$("#Province").val(provinces);
```

But when I use the following code, Eastern Cape gets selected.

```
var provinces = 1;
$("#Province").val(provinces);
```

I want to use the name of the province not the ID of the province, how can I do that?

Regards
Siyabonga

Comment: A value of `select` element can be directly set by `text` property only when the target option element doesn't have `value` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

well you should check the content of options like this :

```
var provinces = "Eastern Cape";
$("#Province option:contains(" + provinces + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

for similar options use this  :

```
$("#Province  option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == provinces ) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');            
  }                        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the option with the required text and use it's `value` to set the dropdown like so, this uses `jquery`:

```
//use .filter() to get the option from the drop down with text = the required text
//then pass it's value to .val() of the dropdown
$('#Province').val($('#Province option').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).html() == "Eastern Cape"; }).val());
```

You could turn this into a function for more dynamic use:

```
function setDropdownByOptionText(dropdown, optionText){
     $(dropdown).val($(dropdown).find('option').filter(function () {
          return $(this).html() == optionText; }).val());
}
```

Then you could call it like so:

```
setDropdownByOptionText($('#Province'), "Eastern Cape");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan